# Fade in strings of text one by one in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to develop a game with libGDX at the moment. Right now, I am attempting to create a short intro to the game.

The short intro is just a solid colour background, with strings of texts (different sizes) fading in one by one.

Right now, my tactic is to create a variable `fade` that starts from 0 and increases by delta each time the game updates. When `fade` is bigger or equal to one, I use an `if` statement to cap it at one.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen{

public static SpriteBatch batch;
private static OrthographicCamera camera;
private static Music music;
private static BitmapFont font;
private static CharSequence title, subTitle;
private static float fade;

public MainMenu() {

    music = AssetLoader.getMainMenuMusic();
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 480, 800);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    title = "Text1";
    subTitle = "Text2";
    fade = 0;

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("CordiaUPC.fnt"),
            Gdx.files.internal("CordiaUPC.png"), false);


}


@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    fade += delta;
    if(fade >= 1) {
       fade = 1;
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    font.setScale(1.0f);
    font.setColor(1, 1, 1, fade);
    font.draw(batch, title, 100, 600);
    font.setScale(0.5f);
    font.draw(batch, subTitle, 200, 500);
    batch.end();

}
```

When I run this, my two lines of text will fade in. However, `fade` will keep updating itself at `1` , which I feel like it's a waste if this is calculating for the entire time the app is running.

Also, I can't figure out how to fade the texts in one by one using this method.

So how should I do this? I have a feeling my way is probably completely wrong, but I'm not familiar enough is libGDX to know how to do it anyway else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could wrap

```
fade += delta;
if(fade >= 1) {
   fade = 1;
}
```

in a `if(fade < 1)` block, but this kind of an optimization is a waste of your time at this stage. It's insignificant, but if you were doing something like this to hundreds of objects in a loop, it would be useful (which is the only reason I suggest it, so you can keep it in mind for future use).

By the way, if you are fading something in, it looks much better to use a curve instead of linear interpolation like you're doing. Libgdx already has built-in helper classes for this kind of thing. You could do it like this:

```
private static final float FADE_IN_TIME = 1f;
private float fadeElapsed = 0;

fadeElapsed += delta;
float fade = Interpolation.fade.apply(fadeElapsed / FADE_IN_TIME);
```

And to stagger the fade of the two objects like you asked about, it only requires an extra parameter:

```
private static final float SUBTITLE_FADE_DELAY = 0.5f;

float fade2 = Interpolation.fade.apply((fadeElapsed-SUBTITLE_FADE_DELAY) / FADE_IN_TIME);

//...

batch.begin();
font.setScale(1.0f);
font.setColor(1, 1, 1, fade);
font.draw(batch, title, 100, 600);
font.setScale(0.5f);
font.setColor(1, 1, 1, fade2);
font.draw(batch, subTitle, 200, 500);
batch.end();
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but could you explain more on why you need `FADE_IN_TIME` ? If the value is one, isn't that just the same as `fadeElapsed` when compared to `fadeElapsed / 1` ?

Comment: It's only the same if you keep it as 1 second. If you omit it, you are hiding what should be a constant. It's generally bad programming practice to hard code constants into your functions or methods, because it makes it harder to find bugs later, it can make bugs more likely if you use a value in multiple places, and you lose the ability to quickly tweak many aspects of your program.